# mongoose.js: How do I remove a property from a subarray of references while using populate and use one of the subarray field as a filter as well?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nosql

I have the following code in node js using mongoose package.

1)How do I remove the field total within the foundations array on the response if I'm using the populate method??. Cause that array is formed by references to another collection.

2) How do I use the "campaigns.state" field to filter only the campaigns that has "ACTIVE" as the state?

The definition:

**FOUNDATION model**

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var foundation = new Schema({

     twitter_account:{type: String, required: true, unique: true},

     name:{type: String, required: true, unique: true},

     pic_path: {type: String, required: true},

     doc_path: {type: String, required: true},

     campaigns: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Campaign'}]
},{
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Foundation', foundation);
```

on the Campaigns model I have the Foundations field which is an array of references to foundations and I want to cut it out on the response to avoid redundancy

```
var campaign = new Schema({

.............

     foundations: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Foundation'}],

......................
}
```

HERE IS THE ROUTE OF THE API WHERE I RETRIEVE THE DATA

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Foundation=require('../models/Foundation');
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var _ = require('lodash');


//get all Foundations
router.get('/get/all', function(req, res, next) {

  var results=Foundation.find({},{twitter_account:1,name:1,campaigns:1})

  .populate('campaigns').exec(function (err, foundation) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log(foundation);
        res.send(foundation);
});

});

module.exports = router;
```

**Here is the response:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "58229b253e1ad628e1ed975e",
    "twitter_account": "@YYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "name": "YYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "campaigns": [
      {
        "_id": "5822a9444aea133044b6eb84",
        "updatedAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.922Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.922Z",
         "total": 0,
        "state": "ACTIVE",
        "__v": 0,
        "end_date": null,
        "foundations": [
          "58229b253e1ad628e1ed975e",
          "58229b253e1ad628e1ed975f"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5822a9444aea133044b6eb85",
        "updatedAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.925Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.925Z",
        "remaining_ammount_to_goal": 500000,
        "total": 0,
        "state": "ACTIVE",
        "__v": 0,
        "end_date": null,
        "foundations": [
          "58229b253e1ad628e1ed975e"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "58229b253e1ad628e1ed975f",
    "twitter_account": "@XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "campaigns": [
      {
        "_id": "5822a9444aea133044b6eb85",
        "updatedAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.925Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.925Z",
        "total": 0,
        "state": "ACTIVE",
        "__v": 0,
        "end_date": null,
        "foundations": [
          "58229b253e1ad628e1ed975e"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Desired response( just want to drop foundation array field within campaigns objects):

```
[
  {
    "_id": "58229b253e1ad628e1ed975e",
    "twitter_account": "@YYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "name": "YYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "campaigns": [
      {
        "_id": "5822a9444aea133044b6eb84",
        "updatedAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.922Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.922Z",
         "total": 0,
        "state": "ACTIVE",
        "__v": 0,
        "end_date": null
      },
      {
        "_id": "5822a9444aea133044b6eb85",
        "updatedAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.925Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.925Z",
        "remaining_ammount_to_goal": 500000,
        "total": 0,
        "state": "ACTIVE",
        "__v": 0,
        "end_date": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "58229b253e1ad628e1ed975f",
    "twitter_account": "@XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "campaigns": [
      {
        "_id": "5822a9444aea133044b6eb85",
        "updatedAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.925Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-11-09T04:42:44.925Z",
        "total": 0,
        "state": "ACTIVE",
        "__v": 0,
        "end_date": null
      }
    ]
```

Any ideas?. Thank you very much!!!

**EDIT**: For future reference, to filter the objects that has state="Active" on the "Campaigns"JSONArray using populate I achieved that using:
  var results=Foundation.find({},{twitter_account:1,name:1,campaigns:1})

```
  .populate({path : 'campaigns' ,select :'-foundations', match:{state:'ACTIVE'}}).exec(function (err, foundation) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log(foundation);
        res.send(foundation);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use populate with select

```
       var results=Foundation.find({},{twitter_account:1,name:1,campaigns:1})
          .populate({path : 'campaigns' ,select :'-foundations'})
          .exec(function (err, foundation) {
                if (err) return handleError(err);
                console.log(foundation);
                res.send(foundation);
        });
```

Just go through the mongoose documentation
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: great answer my friend....I read the documentation on populate and I got the job done...I edited the original post to leave the answer on how to filter on a JSON array property when you use populate.Thank you!!